# directories and files to renaming with Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to rename files by deleting an unwanted character. The script works, but I would also like to rename the directories: how can I do it? Also I would like to look for a set of characters, and not just one at a time.

```
import os
import sys

pathFilesToRename = sys.argv[1]
characterToChange = sys.argv[2]
substitutiveCharacter = sys.argv[3]

#print(percorsoFilesDapathFilesToRenamerinominare)
for dpath, dnames, fnames in os.walk(pathFilesToRename):
    for f in fnames:
        os.chdir(dpath)
        if not f.startswith('.'):
         if f.join(characterToChange):
            os.rename(f, f.replace(characterToChange, substitutiveCharacter))
```

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken `os.rename` can rename directories as well.

Comment: It can, but unfortunately it rename only the files in this case, and I don't know why

Comment: You're iterating only over filenames: `for f in fnames`.

Comment: Thank you very much! I added iteration to the directories. now i wish I could insert a set of characters to search for replacement, instead of one character at a time.